# How to change tikz-qtree tree edge angle

Tags: tikz-trees, tikz-qtree

I am looking to make a tree where the angle of the edge to children is the same at every level. I am aware that this might cause nodes to overlap.

I want something that looks like this:

[image: tree with constant children edge angles]

But unfortunately my tree looks like this:

[image: tree with different children edge angles]

My tree uses this LaTeX:

```tex
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={minimum width=2em,draw,circle},
         blank/.style={draw=none},
         edge from parent/.style=
         {draw,edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}},
         level distance=1cm
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [ .1 [ .2 \edge[blank]; \node[blank]{}; [ .4 \edge[blank]; \node[blank]{}; [ .5 \edge[blank]; \node[blank]{}; [ .6 \edge[blank]; \node[blank]{}; 7 ] ] ] ] 3 ]
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Help is appreciated

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You could add something like `level 1/.style={sibling distance=-1cm}` to the options in the `\tikset` macro.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thank you, unfortunately it does not work. I have tried setting multiple levels to specific sibling distances, but they only work for specific trees and not all

Comment: Do you need to use the `tikz-qtree` package? I have the feeling that it is easier to achieve what you want using a normal Ti*k*z tree or maybe using the `forest` package. Your answer seems to support my feeling …

Comment: Thank you! Forest offers a much nicer syntax. I have added it to my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to recreate the tree in the first image by using tikz `\node` instead of tikz-qtree `\Tree`:

```tex
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw]{1}
  child{node[circle,draw]{2} child[missing] child{node[circle,draw]{4} child[missing] child{node[circle,draw]{5} child[missing] child{node[circle,draw]{6} child[missing] child{node[circle,draw]{7}}} } } }
  child{node[circle,draw]{3}} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: tree with same angle for each child node]

**Edit:**
This can also be done using forest, which has a nicer syntax:

```tex
\begin{forest}
for tree={draw,circle,calign=fixed edge angles}
[1 [2 [,phantom] [4 [,phantom] [5 [,phantom] [6 [,phantom] [7 [,phantom] ]]]]] [3]]
\end{forest}
```

Thanks to @Jasper Habicht for the suggestion to use forest.